# Build Swift Function with Callback with Parameters and Call from ObjectiveC with Autocomplete

Tags: swift, objective-c, callback

I've created a function in Swift that I call from Objective C. It has a callback with parameters. However it won't autocomplete with the parameter names in the callback. It seems that quite some time ago labels in functions are not allowed in swift anymore. Hence the use of the _ to make it build.

Here is the definition of my function in swift...

```
    @objc func myFunction (param1: String, success: @escaping ()->(), failure: @escaping (_ error: NSError?)->())
```

In Objective-C I can make this work but the autocomplete does the following...

```
    [self.swiftClass myFunction:myParam success:^{
        
        // Yay success!
        
    } failure:^(NSError * _Nullable) {
        
        // NO failure!
    }];
```

As you can see the NSError in failure isn't named/labeled. How do I make it so that it will autocomplete properly? Otherwise I have to add the parameter name manually myself. ie. failure:^(NSError * _Nullable **error**).

Comment: Are there any other first party APIs you know of that do this? Perhaps you could take a look at their headers and see how they work

Comment: Everything I've seen so far through many stack overflow searches and googling seem to state that Swift changed the way these parameters were able to be "labeled" and made them mandatory to be essentially "optional". I can't seem to find an examples of code that will assure that the labels come through for the objective c/swift bridge and therefore autocomplete. :( I have to assume it must be possible or this is a glaring omission.

Comment: You're correct, that change *did* happen, but I have no recollection of every having an Objective C method call being auto-completed with the labels copied over. It certainly might be the case, but I don't have any memory of it